# Presenting Modal ViewController leads to SIGABRT

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, sigabrt

I initialize an `UINavigationController` with my custom `UIViewController` subclass. But as soon as I want to present the view controller I get a `SIGABRT` error in Xcode. I have done this many times before and I assume that this problem existis because of other things that might not be correct in my current project. However, I find it very difficult to find the problem behind this phenomenon. So are there some things that you can do which somehow prevent the presentation of a modal view controller?

This is how I present my view controller:

```
- (IBAction)tutorialTouched:(id)sender {

    TutorialViewController *tutorialVC = [[TutorialViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:tutorialVC];
    nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

    // This line leads to `SIGABRT`
    [self presentModalViewController:nav animated:NO];
}
```

Deployment target is 5.0.

**Update:**
This is the information I get when typing `bt` into the console:

```
#0  0x945919c6 in __pthread_kill ()
#1  0x9645bf78 in pthread_kill ()
#2  0x9644cbdd in abort ()
#3  0x003169dc in uncaught_exception_handler ()
#4  0x032010fc in __handleUncaughtException ()
#5  0x02f00f0f in _objc_terminate ()
#6  0x0349e8de in safe_handler_caller ()
#7  0x0349e946 in std::terminate ()
#8  0x0349fb3e in __cxa_rethrow ()
#9  0x02f00e15 in objc_exception_rethrow ()
#10 0x03137de0 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#11 0x03137c9b in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#12 0x035ca7d8 in GSEventRunModal ()
#13 0x035ca88a in GSEventRun ()
#14 0x016b3626 in UIApplicationMain ()
#15 0x00002fad in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff5a8) at /Users/myProject/main.m:14
```

Comment: What does it say in the console?

Comment: Could you please provide the detailed error information in your Xcode debugger console? If the application exits with SIGABRT, there should be some info about exceptions. One possible exception is `NSInvalidArgumentException` if you are on iOS 4.x simulator.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the block (completion) is empty. Try putting some dummy code (NSLog) in it.

Comment: @kuba I updated my answer with the conventional approach which does not work either.

Comment: What class does this code belong to? Is it even a UIViewController?

Comment: @Nic Yes it is a proper `UIViewController` sub class.

Comment: There is an exception and you don't have Exception breakpoint set. There are dozens of SO posts explaining how to do it. Then you'll see what the problem really is.

Comment: your code should work .. I think there is a problem with your viewController .. use the breakpoints and check whats really cause this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was caused due to an Outlet error inside my ViewController. I could not figure it out because the compiler never told me this. Only when I added a `try / catch` around the presentation of the view controller did I get the exception object, which finally told me what was wrong. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for your help.

Comment: This was also my problem. HOW BAD THIS IS, that xcode can not warn about a wrong outlet. I renamed the IBOutlet in the h and m file, but not in the xib file... seems like something that should jump! :)

Answer (score 2):

Blocks got introduced in 4.0, so if you use blocks on a device with a lower iOS you will receive SIGABRT. 
Check if it exist by using respondsToSelector and a fallback method.

```
if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]){
        [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:^{}];
}else{
    [self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: The problem occurs also when using the conventional way. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the app on iOS 4.x simulator, it will crash with SIGABRT because of `NSInvalidArgumentException` and something like `unrecognized selector sent`. The reason is that `presentModalViewController:animated:completion:` doesn't exist before iOS 5.0.

Use `presentModalViewController:animated:` for previous versions of iOS. Since it is marked as deprecated in iOS 5.0, you can do this for future maintainance:

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)]) {
    [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:^{}];
} else {
    [self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
}
```

See [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more information.

Comment: The problem also occurs with the conventional way of showing the modal. I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Additional error info in Xcode console may be helpful to find the root cause.

Comment: Unfortunately not. The program just jumps to the `main` function and says `Thread 1: Program received signal: 'SIGABRT'`. That's all I am getting :-(

Comment: Try to enter `bt` and press return in the console to see whether it provides some trace information for you?

Comment: The information doesn't tell what's the exception... I suggest use the method in "Breaking on Exceptions" section of http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DebuggingTechniques to print the exception object.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple, drop the block code and chage the last line to

```
[self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

in Nav you can do any additional code with the use of ViewDidLoad

Why does it crash?

It crashes because the presentViewController:animated:completion: method of UIViewController is not available on iOS 4.3. It was introduced in iOS 5, your code most likely is set for iOS < 5.0 - Thus crashes - QED

Comment: ok, lets try this, change your target to ios 5 and run - just as a reality check. if this still crashes you will need to post some more code as I assume the issue is located somewhere else. nevertheless I can confirm that my original answer works on a test project I just made.

Comment: The target is already set to 5.0 additionally the same error occurs if I use the conventional way of presenting the modal view controller.